# How to break a table in ABCpdf

Tags: asp.net, css, pdf-generation, abcpdf, html-to-pdf

I'm using **ABCpdf** to generate a **PDF** of an **HTML** page. What I need is to break a table's last rows which can't fit into a page instead of the table skipping into a completely new page. [I've attached a screen shot here](https://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ac8rrd&s=8).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use Gecko engine with ABCPdf.  I think the Gecko Engine was added in version 8 or so.

see: [Gecko Engine Information](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/1-engine.htm)

Also see: [Page break when HTML to PDF with AbcPdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291447/page-break-when-html-to-pdf-with-abcpdf)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your HTML to cause a page break.

```
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
```